# /search intitle arg is case sensitive

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

This seriously cripples any search capabilities.

Consider:

http://api.stackapps.com/0.8/search?intitle=soapi&order=desc&sort=activity
vs

http://api.stackapps.com/0.8/search?intitle=Soapi&order=desc&sort=activity
vs

http://api.stackapps.com/0.8/search?intitle=SOAPI&order=desc&sort=activity

This also begs the question "How many other textual parameters are case sensitive?"

it is my opinion that there should be no case sensitivity anywhere in the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search `intitle` is now case insensitive.

Answer (score -2):

I somewhat agree. I think that if there are case-sensitive parameters in the API, they should have some means by which they can be made case-insensitive.

What I think this should boil down to is the addition of a parameter like `case-sensitive=true`.

Comment: Right, everyone would start using case-sensitive=false in their search.

Comment: @Gan: Well the default would be the opposite.